# Trigger on ChatTranscript not Firing on Insert

Tags: apex, trigger, chat

I am having trouble making my trigger work
I set up a trigger on the ChatTranscript object and I would like it to fire up ONLY when it is created.
But for some reason it is not... I tried to play with the logs here is my current code ( for testing)

```
trigger ChatTranscriptTrigger on LiveChatTranscript (after insert, before insert, after update) {
    system.debug('start');
    if (Trigger.isInsert){
        system.debug('Is Insert');
        if (Trigger.isAfter){
            system.debug('triggered after');
            SendEventToBOFromChatTranscript.afterInsert(Trigger.New);
        }
        if (Trigger.isAfter){
            system.debug('triggered before');
            //SendEventToBOFromChatTranscript.afterInsert(Trigger.New);
        }
       
    }
    if (Trigger.isUpdate){
        system.debug('Is update');
    }
}
```

When I start a chat session, I have my pre chat, I enter my first name, last name and Email .. and in my salesforce I accept the chat
When I check the logs only the isUpdate is fired...

not the IsInsert. Am I doing something wrong ?
thx you

Comment: So you don't see 'Is Insert' log at all?

Comment: when the chat is ended by a customer or an agent—the chat transcript is created as soon as the agent closes the chat window

Comment: @AndyHitchings No I do not ;(

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi Not using omni channel it is before..

Comment: did you check the logs for `Automated Process` user?

Comment: In the log for automated user I can see it .. but the data is not updated ..